# Problem accessing the Market

Tags: google-play-store, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10

I have a Sony Ericsson Xperia with Android. I can't download from the Market because there is some Gmail account that I don't have an idea how it got there.

This means that I don't know the password! I have tried to change that email but I can't so what is your suggestion what should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Go to `Settings > Accounts and Settings`, click on the account that you don't know the password and then click the `Remove Account` button on the bottom. So next time you open up Android Market you'll be prompted to type in a new account